# "bootstrap min css 1 failed to load resource: net::err_file_not_found"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting an error "bootstrap min css 1 failed to load resource: net::err_file_not_found" 
on my console when I'm trying to implement bootstrap into my code.
I downloaded bootstrap 4.5 and jquery 3.5.1. bootstrap.min.css file is saved inside the css folder but i'm unable to  understand where the mistake is.
It shows me the error in this line of the code 
`link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"`

Comment: I was able to solve the issue. Thank you.

Comment: "I was able to solve the issue". how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please provide more info about your folder structure.** If the file actually exists you just made a small mistake writing the path. For instance: href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" or href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" depending on the location of your file. Just click-right the file and make sure the actual location is correct.
Hope it helps! Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below link. If this works then there is an issue in your local path.

Instead using the local file you can use the CDN link that I have mentioned below

````
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">```
````